# MySQL data transfer

Tags: mysql

The company i have recently started working for have given me quite a horrible task. They have a current database (in use) and have now recently created a new database to be used by the Web Application. However the problem is that the old database table names and field names do not match the new database table names and field names.

Current Structure Example:

```
Table Name: Articles
Field Name: ID, ArticleTitle, ArticleContent
```

New Database Example:

```
Table Name: eHArticle
Field Name: eHArtID, eHArt_Title, eHArt_Content
```

I need to transfer the data from the old db to the new one. The current database holds over 2000 records. 
Is there a way to transfer the information from the current database and into the new database even tho the table names and field names are different?

The ideas behind the creation of the new database was to implement FK Relations and normalisation. This new database and ERD was designed and implemented before i got to the position and table names and structures are not allowed to be changed.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a query in your old database like

```
SELECT ID AS eHArtID, 
  ArticleTitle AS eHArt_Title, 
  ArticleContent AS eHArt_Content
FROM Articles
```

...then you can export it, and import directly to the new one.

Comment: Thank you. this works well. now i just have to import the exported data into the new database

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
USE [NewDB]
INSERT INTO eHArticle (eHArtID, eHArt_Title, eHArt_Content)
SELECT ID, ArticleTitle, ArticleContent
FROM [OldDB]..Articles
```